# Trocar ícone de botão de acordo com status

Tags: javascript, react, button

Possuo uma tabela de orçamentos e quando o orçamento estiver aprovado preciso que o ícone fique cinza e quando estiver com o status aguardando o ícone será azul, esses ícones são imagens que estão na pasta do projeto. Como faço essa condição?
No momento apenas a opção azul desse ícone está aparecendo e é possível seguir para a página de edição, que está a seguir.

```html
  <Button
    title="Apagar"
    aria-label="delete"
    onClick={() =>
      handleSaveQuotationToDelete({
        id: quotation.id,
        name: quotation.name,
      })
    }
    size="small"
  >
    <img 
      className="actions" 
      src={edit} 
      alt="ícone de edição" 
    />
  </Button>
```

Para o ícone cinza ele deveria ser assim

```html
  <Button
    title="Editar"
    aria-label="edit"
    onClick={() => {
      handleGetQuotation(quotation.id)}
    }
    size="small"
    disabled={
      disableEditIcon || quotation.status === 'Aprovado'
    }
  >
      <img 
        className="actions" 
        src={noedit} 
        alt="ícone de edição" 
      />
  </Button>
```

Qual a melhor maneira de executar?

Answer (score -3):

Podes usar uma condição ternária para mostrar o botão que pretendes em cada caso.

```
        {(disableEditIcon || quotation.status === 'Aprovado') ? (
              <Button
                  title="Apagar"
                  aria-label="delete"
                  onClick={() =>
                  handleSaveQuotationToDelete({
                      id: quotation.id,
                      name: quotation.name,
                  })
                  }
                  size="small"
              >
                  <img 
                  className="actions" 
                  src={edit} 
                  alt="ícone de edição" 
                  />
              </Button>
        ): (
              <Button
                  title="Editar"
                  aria-label="edit"
                  onClick={() => {
                  handleGetQuotation(quotation.id)}
                  }
                  size="small"
                  disabled={
                  disableEditIcon || quotation.status === 'Aprovado'
                  }
              >
                  <img 
                      className="actions" 
                      src={noedit} 
                      alt="ícone de edição" 
                  />
              </Button> 
        )
      }
```